# Google+ signin unsing Safari private browser (gapi.auth2.init)

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

Google social sign seems to work in all browsers include Safari; but not when using Safari private browsing. The Google sign-in pop appears; you can enter your email/password but once authenticated the popup remains with a white screen. Cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Am using `gapi.auth2.init` but we never reach the callback method `onSuccess`.
This is basically taken from: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state

The error that appears in the console is:

> QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add
>   something to storage that exceeded the quota.

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var auth2;
var initClient = function() {   
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
       auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
        });
        auth2.attachClickHandler('customBtn', {}, onSuccess, onFailure);
    });
};

var onSuccess = function(user) {
    console.log('Signed in as ' + user.getBasicProfile().getName());
 };
var onFailure = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};

function startApp() {
    initClient();
}
 <body>
  <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn" />
  <p>Demo</p>
</body>
</html>
<script>startApp();</script>
```

Comment: It appears that private browsing Safari does not allow local storage; which I believe the google api's is using. Does that imply that we cannot use G+ sign-in in Safari private browsing?

Comment: Local Storage works in Safari Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4) (on OSX) private mode - just checked my app. 
br.

Comment: @JohannesFerner Am using 'Yosemite 10.10.5' with Safari version 9.0.2 (10601.3.9). Inspecting the console on the popup I see `QuotaExceededError`.